# How to stop publishing metrics but still keep accessible under /metrics in spring boot micrometer?

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I want to keep collecting `jvm` and other metrics, but just don't want to push all of them to cloudwatch or prometheus (or anything else).

If I do like this

```
@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> customizer() {
    return (registry) -> registry.config()
        .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm"));
}
```

it stops publishing to cloudwatch but at the same time, the metrics are gone from `/actuator/metrics/` as well.

Is there anyway I can keep them accessible under `/actuator/metrics/` but stop pushing those to remote metrics collector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for how to expose Spring Boot Actuator `metrics` endpoint but not to publish metrics to any remote meter registry like Prometheus, just adding the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator` without any monitoring system-specific dependency like `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus` should work. This is [a working sample](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot).

However, based on [the project owner's comment](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/488#issuecomment-373249656), the endpoint is intended for a diagnostic purpose only, so you should use one of monitoring system-specific meter registries for monitoring purposes as follows:

> The actuator endpoint is at best a toy, a diagnostic tool. The real
>   heavy lifting of structuring the data for publishing happens in each
>   registry implementation.

UPDATED:

Based on your comment, if I understand correctly, you want to expose all metrics on the `metrics` endpoint but publish some of them to a remote meter registry.

For doing so, you can add a `SimpleMeterRegistry` for the `metrics` endpoint and add a `MeterRegistryCustomizer` for the remote meter registry to add some `MeterFilter`.

See [this commit](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/commit/31417c218494c882d46f40823df87edb477c8534) and [this branch](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/so-51581021) for a Prometheus example.

Comment: Thats not what I want. I want to publish to remote meter registry, but only some of them. Like all non-jvm metrics. But when I add that meter filter, all jvm metrics are removed from being published, as well as removed from the actuator endpoint.